# Uploading a file using hidden input field

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload, input

I'm trying to call the upload file function from a href link and even though the browse box is being displayed, I can't run the validation on the selected file.  Here is the code that I have:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('input[id=formmedia]').click();"><div class="sidebarSectionLink">Click here to add files</div></a> //Calls the browse box

<input type="file" id="formmedia" style="display: none;"> //Hidden input

//Post Photo Jquery
$('#formmedia').blur(function()
{
var pic=$("#formmedia").val();
if(pic.length < 1){
    $('.sidebarSectionLink').html("Please Add A Photo").removeClass("success").addClass("error");
    picok = 2;
}
else if(pic.indexOf('jpg') === -1 && pic.indexOf('jpeg') === -1 && pic.indexOf('png') === -1 && pic.indexOf('gif') === -1){
    $('.sidebarSectionLink').html("Invalid File Format").removeClass("success").addClass("error");
    picok = 2;
}
else {
    picok = 1;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('formmedia').onchange = uploadOnChange;

function uploadOnChange(){
    //Validation here
}
```

or the jQuery version

```
$('#formmedia').change(function(){
    //validation
});
```

Because the field is hidden, onblur won't fire, but changes can happen even on hidden items.